# Cmd is not finding my files. I can see them in file explorer, but am unable to see them or access them in cmd

Tags: python, django, powershell, cmd, onedrive

[image: Results from dir command]

[image: In file explorer]

I am unable to access bookbuddy or activate my python virtualenv.  The problem is not specific to this Project-BookBuddy directory.  There are strange and inconsistent results in other directories as well.  I recently synced with oneDrive.  IDK if that has anything to do with this.

Comment: This depends. Is the file you want empty, or does it have files?

Comment: Have you tried `dir /A`?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, I think it depends on the directory and file attributes you want to see.
Please run this command and see if you can see all the files.

`dir /ah`

if you would be able to see all the files with this command, it says your directories attributes are hidden by system or user.

Comment: Here is what is returned - C:\Users\Jeff\Desktop\Project-BookBuddy>dir /ah
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is EC8D-42D7

 Directory of C:\Users\Jeff\Desktop\Project-BookBuddy

File Not Found

C:\Users\Jeff\Desktop\Project-BookBuddy>